# Best way to set a conditional output filter (head or output "as is")

Tags: bash, pipe, head

For testing purpose, I want to activate or not a filtering with the command head.

For example, the command below could outputs a lot of lines

```
#!/bin/bash
produce_a_lot_of_lines
```

I want to set on demand a filter with `head`, depending on a variable. A way The sample below works:

```
#!/bin/bash
function filter() {
  [[ "$HEAD" =~ [0-9]+ ]] && head -n $HEAD || cat
}
produce_a_lot_of_lines | filter
```

Is there a cleaner/more efficient/better way to achieve this?

Comment: `if [[ "$HEAD" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then PaLoL | head -n "$HEAD"; else PaLoL; fi`

Comment: @mosvy, upvoted comment. It repeats `PaLoL`, but avoid additional `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more reusable way :

```
function filter() {
    local nb_lines="$1"; shift
    if  [[ "$nb_lines" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        "$@" | head -n "$nb_lines"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

filter "$HEAD" produce_a_lot_of_lines
```